# Spectrum of the limit of a sequence of operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of bounded (perhaps compact?) operators on a complex Hilbert space, which all have the same spectrum. Suppose the sequence converges in operator norm (or perhaps in a weaker way?) to an operator $A$. Does this imply that $A$ has the same spectrum?

Suppose the spectra of the $A_n$ converge as sets (perhaps monotonely?) to some subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Is this related to the spectrum of the limit?

Comment: Norm convergence is what you need here; weaker notions won't be enough. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1235819)

Comment: An example of what goes wrong with convergence in strong operator topology: let $P_n$ be the rank-1 projection onto the $n$th coordinate axis. Then $P_n\to 0$ but the spectrum of each $P_n$ is $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: The question is answered by the material linked by Michelle and links therein. In particular the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04641 linked there examines conditions for spectra of operators to converge in hausdorff metric. I might work out proofs for strong versions of the hypotheses in the question when I have time using these materials.