# Can the spectrum of a (strong operator) limit be bigger than the limit of spectra?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of bounded, self-adjoint operators converging to $A$ in the strong operator topology. Even if the spectra of all $A_n$ coincide, the spectrum of $A$ could be a strict subset of these spectra (as noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404019/spectrum-of-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-operators)).

I am interested in the reverse direction: **If $\forall n:\sigma(A_n)\subseteq\sigma(A_{n+1})$** (or even just with equality) **, do we have $\sigma(A)\subseteq \bigcup_n\sigma(A_n)$ or could the spectrum of the limit contain *more* values?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the closure on the right, but then it is true:

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sigma(A_n)}$. Then there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the open ball $B(\lambda,\varepsilon)$  does not intersect with any $\sigma(A_n)$. In particular, as $A_n - \lambda I$ is self-adjoint, $\inf\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \|(A_n - \lambda I)x\| \geq \varepsilon$. It follows that
$$\|(A - \lambda I)x\| = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \|(A_n - \lambda I)x\| \geq \varepsilon\|x\|$$
for all $x \in H$. As $A - \lambda I$ is self-adjoint, this implies that $A - \lambda I$ is invertible. Thus $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \sigma(A)$.