# Spectrum of a sequence of operator from limit operator spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Suppose $T$ is a bounded operator, $T_n$ a sequence of bounded operators convergent to $T$. If we know the spectrum of $T$, is it true that the spectrum of $T_n$ converges to the spectrum of $T$? Would have been different if the operators are of finite rank, so the spectrum is formed only by eigenvalue?

Comment: This answer might be relevant  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40801/405726

Comment: What topology do you put on the spectrum of an operator so that you can speak about convergence?

Comment: I am just interested in the case $T_n\to T$ iff $||T_n-T||\to0$, where $||T||=\sup_{||x||\leq1}||Tx||$ (working in an Hilbert space)